# what ml algorithms are used for friend suggestions or item recommendations?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, clustering, k-means

As per my idea unsupervised learning clustering algorithms like k-means, HCA is used for recommendations stuff. I just wanted to know what are advanced algorithms used for this type of work in social network (fb,twitter) & e-commerce websites. Are classification algorithms used for this kind of work?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to DataScience.SE! The best way to get up to speed on a problem is to read the latest surveys. Here are some I found with a quick search:

- [Recommender Systems](http://paper.sciencenet.cn/upload/news/file/2012/10/20121071511108170.pdf) ([alternative link](http://doc.rero.ch/record/30535))
- [Recommender systems survey](http://romisatriawahono.net/lecture/rm/survey/information%20retrieval/Bobadilla%20-%20Recommender%20Systems%20-%202013.pdf)
- [A literature review and classification of recommender systems research](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0957417412002825)
- [Link prediction in complex networks: A survey](http://icdic.org/media/ckeditor_uploads/buaa/2013/08/17/Link%20Prediction%20in%20Complex%20Networks_A%20Survey.pdf)
- [A survey of link prediction in social networks](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Survey-of-Link-Prediction-in-Social-Networks-Hasan-Zaki/e7d30fefe1b99c21813873f976e46d03dc82b4fc/pdf)

You can find more by searching for "recommender systems" or "link prediction".
If you have any specific questions after reading them we can help but there is no way we can do justice to a broad question like the one in your title when the articles take dozens of pages to answer the same question.